# PHPMailer worked for a while, but now is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, phpmailer

I made a form on a website using PHPMailer. My form was working fine for a while, but now it doesn't. I relatively new to PHP, so I'm not sure where the problem is..

So this is my PHPMailer file "mail-devis.php" :

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;               //Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();       
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         //Send using SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.agencebazar.com';           //Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                       //Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = "MY EMAIL";                 //SMTP username
$mail->Password   = "MY PASSWORD";              //SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port       = 465;                              

//Recipients
$recipient = $_POST['prenom'] . " " . $_POST['name'] ;
$mail->From= $_POST["email"];
$mail->SetFrom($_POST["email"],$recipient);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);
$mail->AddAddress("RECEIVER ADDRESS");


//Content

$name = $_POST['name'];
$prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Devis - TridyMaker';
$message = $_POST['message'];

$mailheader = "From:" . $prenom . " ". $name . "<" . $email . ">\r\n";


// Set content-type header for sending HTML email 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// Additional headers 
$headers .= 'From: ' . $prenom . ' ' . $Name . '<' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";


$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

$txt = "<h3>Demande de devis </h3>
<p>" . $message . "</p>\n\n 
<h3>Client</h3>
<p><b>Prénom:</b> " . $prenom . "</p>
<p><b>Nom:</b> ". $name . "</p>
<p><b>Portable:</b> " . $telephone . "</p>
<p><b>E-mail:</b> " . $email . "</p>";

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = $subject . ' via Site Web';
$mail->Body    = $txt;

$mail->send();
?>
```

I have a script that validate my form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#load-image').hide()
        $("#contact-devis").on('submit', (function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var valid;
            valid = validateContactForm();
            if (valid) {
                var $loadImage = $('#load-image').show(); // show loading image
                var $mailSubmit = $('#form_button').prop('disabled', true); // disable the submit button
                $.ajax({
                    url: "mail-devis.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#mail-status").html("Message envoyé avec succès!");
                        $("#mail-status").css('padding', '2vh 0px');
                        $('#contact-devis')[0].reset();
                        $loadImage.hide(); // hide loading image
                        $mailSubmit.prop('disabled', false); // enable the submit button
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $("#mail-status").html("Le message n'a pas pu être envoyé.");
                        $loadImage.hide(); // hide loading image
                        $mailSubmit.prop('disabled', false); // enable the submit button
                    }

                });
            }
        }));

        function validateContactForm() {
            var valid = true;
            $(".info").html("");
          


            $(".input-field").css('border', 'white 1px solid');
            var userName = $("#name_input").val();
            var userPrenom = $("#prenom_input").val();
            var userPhone = $("#phone_input").val();
            var userEmail = $("#email_input").val();
            var subject = $("#subject_input").val();
            var content = $("#message_input").val();



            if (userName == "") {
                $("#userName-info").html("Obligatoire.");
                $("#name_input").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (userPrenom == "") {
                $("#userPrenom-info").html("Obligatoire.");
                $("#prenom_input").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (userPhone == "") {
                $("#userPhone-info").html("Obligatoire.");
                $("#phone_input").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (!userPhone.match(/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im)) {
                $("#userPhone-info").html("Numéro invalide.");
                $("#phone_input").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (userEmail == "") {
                $("#userEmail-info").html("Obligatoire.");
                $("#email_input").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (!userEmail.match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
                $("#userEmail-info").html("Adresse courriel invalide.");
                $("#email_input").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
                valid = false;
            }

            if (subject == "") {
                $("#subject-info").html("Obligatoire.");
                $("#subject_input").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (content == "") {
                $("#userMessage-info").html("Obligatoire.");
                $("#message_input").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
                valid = false;
            }
            return valid;
        }
    })
</script>
```

So there's probably something I didn't do right at the start and now it won't work. Just this morning I was able to send some email through the form. It is as if there was a limit. What can I do?

Comment: Are you getting any output from the debug setting in phpmailer? Your problem  description is currently very vague

Comment: if your code was working fine and your website is on shared hosting, there is an email sending limitation on shared hosting. please contact your service provider in this case!

Comment: It is on a shared hosting on OVH. The problem is that it is not a form that get used often.. I went on my error log and this was the error :

[Tue Sep 26 19:06:31 2023] [error] [client ***] [host ***] AH10141: FastCGI: comm with server "****/www/mail-devis.php" aborted: idle timeout (160 sec), referer: ''My page''

Comment: I don't know if it change anything, but the SMTP is setup with my personal email (WHC) and the website is for a client on OVH. I don't have access to their domain and their email setup.

Comment: It looks like your host might be blocking outbound SMTP, or they may indeed have a limit. It's not clear how you're runnig this script - it should produce quite noisy output as it has debug output enabled. All the stuff you have in their setting headers and boundaries is not relevant when you're using PHPMailer. Also `$mail->SetFrom($_POST["email"],$recipient);` is forgery, and will prevent your messages from being delivered. You may be better off starting again with clean code, such as [this example contact form](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps).